# Does array data not persist if the array is not recreated on each loop?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have 2 ways of answering the leetcode question 957 Prison Cells after N days and was wondering why 1 way works and another doesn't I'll show below. I don't know the terminology to ask this question more specifically but basically why does having the temp array outside the for loops not work but having it inside does?

I have tried to search but because I don't really know the terminology for the issue I couldn't find a result

```
// does not work
class Solution {
    public int[] prisonAfterNDays(int[] cells, int N) {
        int[] temp = new int[cells.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < cells.length - 1; j++) {

                    if((cells[j - 1] == 0 && cells[j + 1] == 0) || (cells[j - 1] == 1 && cells[j + 1] == 1)) {
                        temp[j] = 1;
                    } else {
                        temp[j] = 0;
                    }

            }
            cells = temp;
        }

        return cells;
    }
}
```

```
// Does work
class Solution {
    public int[] prisonAfterNDays(int[] cells, int N) {

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int[] temp = new int[cells.length];
            for(int j = 1; j < cells.length - 1; j++) {

                    if((cells[j - 1] == 0 && cells[j + 1] == 0) || (cells[j - 1] == 1 && cells[j + 1] == 1)) {
                        temp[j] = 1;
                    } else {
                        temp[j] = 0;
                    }

            }
            cells = temp;
        }

        return cells;
    }
}
```

Just wondering the terminology and reason why the code having the array in the for loop works but outside the for loop doesn't.

Comment: Because you do `cells = temp;` and after first iteration everything is operating on the same array and doesn't make sense anymore. In second one you are recreating `temp` with each iteration, so there is no such problem.

Comment: Your algorithm appears to be a simplified version of [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).